# Can a person still fart after death?

Tags: biology, mortality

I read it [here](http://graphjam.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/farts.jpg) and I couldn't believe it.

So can a person still fart after dying ?

Comment: Also: Is it a person after it dies?

Comment: @boehj  a dead person ?

Comment: For those wanting to chase this one up, the claim from that infographic comes from [two](http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/786043/facts_about_farts_passing_gas_facts_pg2.html?cat=5) of the [references](http://www.heptune.com/farts.html). The authors are [Michy Lynn](http://contributor.yahoo.com/user/11173/michy_lynn.html) & Brenna Lorenz, respectively. Neither seem to be an authoritative source on this area (e.g. pathologist, proctologist). The 2nd last link is broken it seems.

Comment: Not intentionally! I can't find any cites that' aren't behind a paywall, but paper abstract seem to indicate that 7-10% of normal intestinal gases are from bacterial decomposition, while the majority appears to be from ingested air (nitrogen mostly, which is not absorbable). It is not a stretch to imagine a dead body may harbor bacteria in the gut.

Comment: Perhaps a full answer later, but anecdotally I have seen this quite a few times.  Gasses will continue to escape from a body after death and as it decomposes.  Sometimes this gas will take the path of least resistance, escaping from either end of the digestive tract, sounding like a burp or fart, however as decomp continues gas buildup often increases and the structures keeping it inside the body decay needless to say, this can cause some extremely messy situations I won't describe here, but google exploding casket syndrome.

Comment: @Monkey So I assume that either you work a lot with dead people or you’re just an amateur mass murderer?

Comment: @Konrad, Why amateur?

Comment: @konrad Sadly I failed my chainsaw decapitation exam and they wouldn't let me into the serial killers union, so I had to go into medicine.

Comment: @Monkey Tuesday:  ...and the exam taker, is he/she still alive?

Comment: @picakhu Well, either professional (“work a lot with dead people”) or amateur. Seems like I botched the joke. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, it can happen after death, but only SHORTLY after death.

This is due to the contracting and expanding of the related muscles, which do not necessarily "shut down" immediately after death.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatulence

Two or three hours after death, rigor mortis sets in. This is a chemical stiffening of the muscles that prevents the kind of activity described above.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigor_mortis

So the "window" doesn't last very long.

Comment: The first reference to Wikipedia does not seem to contain anything to support your claim. If you believe it does, perhaps you could pull some quotes from it to show that that is the case. (NB: Wikipedia isn't a great primary reference in the first place, except to provide general background information.)